# How do I get clang to dump the AST without color?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++, ansi-colors

Using `clang-check` to dump a source code's AST, can be done with the following command:

```
$ clang-check -ast-dump file.c --
```

However, the output of this command will appear colorful within the terminal.
When I direct the output to a file, I'm stuck with all of the color escape codes:

```
$ clang-check -ast-dump file.c -- > out.txt
```

**example:**

```
[0;1;32mTranslationUnitDecl[0m[0;33m 0x227c5c0[0m <[0;33m<invalid sloc>[0m> [0;33m<invalid sloc>[0m
[0;34m|-[0m[0;1;32mTypedefDecl[0m[0;33m 0x227cac0[0m <[0;33m<invalid sloc>[0m> [0;33m<invalid sloc>[0m implicit[0;1;36m __int128_t[0m [0;32m'__int128'[0m
[0;34m|-[0m[0;1;32mTypedefDecl[0m[0;33m 0x227cb20[0m <[0;33m<invalid sloc>[0m> [0;33m<invalid sloc>[0m implicit[0;1;36m __uint128_t[0m [0;32m'unsigned __int128'[0m
[0;34m|-[0m[0;1;32mTypedefDecl[0m[0;33m 0x227ce70[0m <[0;33m<invalid sloc>[0m> [0;33m<invalid sloc>[0m implicit[0;1;36m __builtin_va_list[0m [0;32m'__va_list_tag [1]'[0m
...
```

**Is there a flag to disable colors in clang-check?**
I tried adding the following flag, but it did not work:

```
--extra-arg="--no-color-diagnostics"
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are almost correct. Try

```
$ clang-check -ast-dump test.c --extra-arg="-fno-color-diagnostics" --
```

Additionally, `-fno-diagnostics-color` and `-fdiagnostics-color=never` also seems to work

Reference: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#formatting-of-diagnostics