# > and &> produce different results

Tags: bash, macos, unix, pipe, io-redirection

I'm trying to save stdout of a command to output file `output.txt`

I can't understand why when I use `&>` everything is okay and when I use `>` some strange symbols like `[0m[0;1;32m` appear randomly throughout the file.

What could cause that?

My investigations shows that these symbols are terminal coloring. But why they disappear when I use &>?

Comment: What is the command?

Comment: These look like ASCII escape sequences (e.g. to provide coloured output in the shell), but I'm not sure why they would be visible in one case and not in the other.

Comment: yup, exactly, I realized that myself. the command is ast-dump from clang, I don't understand, why &> manages to filter it out

Comment: Those symbols look like termcap escape codes used to colourise output. Commands sometimes produce such coloured output when stdout is a terminal and revert to plain text when stdout is not a terminal eg a pipe or a disc file. &> redirects both stdout and stderr so it's a bit perplexing why that would happen - as @rghome said, please specify the command.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447542/how-do-i-get-clang-to-dump-the-ast-without-color

Comment: @wef tried that with no luck :(

Comment: What happens, if you do `... ast-dump ... > log 2>&1`? And how is the output if you do `... ast-dump ... 2>log`?

Comment: Redirecting standard error affects standard output? That sounds a little bit broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably checks whether `stderr` is connected to a terminal and if it is than it uses color control codes. When you redirect with `&>` both `stdout` and `stderr` are not connected to a terminal, so no colour codes are used.

Comment: I also assume this. A kind of "prove" would be to execute `command` and `command 2>/dev/null`. The first invocation should have colored output, but not the second.